# Не получается запустить сайт на Rust

Tags: html, rust

[image: структура проекта]
Структура проекта

main.rs

```
#![feature(proc_macro_hygiene, decl_macro)]
#[macro_use] extern crate rocket;
use rocket_contrib::templates::Template;
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[get("/")]
fn index() -> Template {
    let mut context = HashMap::new();
    context.insert("message", "Hello, World!");
    Template::render("index", &context)
}

fn rocket() -> rocket::Rocket {
    rocket::ignite()
        .mount("/", routes![index])
        .attach(Template::fairing())
}

fn main() {
    rocket().launch();
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Rocket Rust Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "my-rocket-project"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
rocket = "0.4.11"
rocket_contrib = { version = "0.4.11", features = ["tera_templates"] }
```

Вывод:

```
GET / text/html:
    => Matched: GET / (index)
    => Error: Template 'index' does not exist.
    => Known templates: 
    => Searched in '"D:\\Development\\Rust\\my-rocket-project\\templates"'.
    => Outcome: Failure
    => Warning: Responding with 500 Internal Server Error catcher.
    => Response succeeded.
```

Comment: В [документации](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.4/rocket_contrib/templates/index.html#discovery) сказано, что поддерживаются только расширения `.tera` и `.hbs`

Answer (score 0):

Переименуйте файл `index.html` в `index.tera` и перепроверьте дефолтную папку с шаблонами.